# Right align button with the textbox

Tags: html, css

Any advice on how to simply align the button with the right of the textbox in this example will be appreciated (it is a couple of pixels to the left for some reason - may just be me?):

```
<input type="text" class="input"/>
<input type="button" value="alignment ok" class="left"/>
<input type="button" value="alignment bad" class="right"/>
```

css

```
.input {
  width: 100%
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

[codepen here](http://cdpn.io/jlJdy)

Comment: simply remove your css. it will be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that width:100% will stretch first input to 100% of the screen, but input box aligned to right will be aligned by body tag.
This will do the trick:

```
body,input {
margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use reset CSS for your style.

```
body{
    padding:0px;
margin: 0px auto;    
}
```

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/talebihamid/72KVq/)

Answer (score 1):

use

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jhiuA)

```
.input {
  width: 100%
}
.right {
  float: right;
  position:relative;
}
body{
    padding:0px;
margin: 0px auto;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set `box-sizing` property your buttons are properly aligned

```
.input {
  width: 100%; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hGcme

---

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
.input {
  width: 100%
}
.right {
  float: right;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CkL2w/3/)**

**Output:**

[image]

**[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/CkL2w/3/embedded/result/)**